# Is it possible to test if a pixel is on a bresenham generated line without generating the line?

Tags: geometry

I have a pixel **P** on a grid. I want to know if that pixel will be on the [bresenham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) generated line between **P0** and **P1** without actually generating the line. Is this possible to come up with such a determinant?

Comment: Do you mean other than the way it shows you on the page you linked to, in the "Line equation" section? ;)

Comment: The linked article shows how to generate a bresenham line. It does not as far as I can see provide a predicate to see if a random pixel is on the generated line without actually generating all the pixels.

Comment: @AndrewMorton the section you link to is for real numbers not pixels.

Comment: "As an example, the line...." it goes on to rearrange the equation, then demonstrates how to test if a point is on the line. In the "Method" section it states "pixel centers have integer coordinates", so all you have to do is round your numbers to the correct integer and test.

Comment: I'm not looking to see if a pixel is on the real line. I'm looking to see if it is on the bresenham line. Different thing. Or to think about it differently. Given a point that is on the real line can you tell me the pixel that will be generated without running the full algorithm. In this case the answer will be no. However my question is subtly different but I suspect the answer is still no.

Comment: If you feel that I am mistaken please add a worked answer showing it and if it is correct I'll give you the points.

Comment: In case of DDA simple clamping should be enough but Bresenham is tricky. I am afraid that you will need to solve the recurrence for integration of parameter `error=f(major axis)` during Bresenham line rasterization (without the `-1`) for main axis and then the difference in minor axis would be `floor(error)`

Comment: @bradgonesurfing I've done that.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the example from [Wikipedia: Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm) with a line from (1,1) to (11,5):

[image: Pixels drawn with Bresenham's line algorithm]

and code derived from the pseudocode sample:

```vb
Module Module1

    Dim chart(15, 9) As String

    Class Point
        Property X As Double
        Property Y As Double

        Sub New(x As Double, y As Double)
            Me.X = x
            Me.Y = y
        End Sub
        Sub New()
            ' empty constructor
        End Sub
    End Class

    Sub ClearChart()
        For i = 0 To 15
            For j = 0 To 9
                chart(i, j) = "·"
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Sub ShowChart(title As String)
        If title.Length > 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine(title)
        End If

        For j = 0 To 9
            For i = 0 To 15
                Console.Write(chart(i, j))
            Next
            Console.WriteLine()
        Next

        Console.WriteLine()

    End Sub

    Sub Plot(p As Point)
        Plot(p.X, p.Y)
    End Sub

    Sub Plot(x As Double, y As Double)
        chart(CInt(Math.Round(x, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)), CInt(Math.Round(y, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))) = "█"
    End Sub

    Sub DrawLine(p1 As Point, p2 As Point)
        ' use Bresenham's line algorithm
        Dim Δx = p2.X - p1.X
        Dim Δy = p2.Y - p1.Y
        Dim err As Double = 0.0
        Dim Δerr = Math.Abs(Δy / Δx)
        Dim y As Integer = CInt(p1.Y)
        Dim yDirn = Math.Sign(p2.Y - p1.Y)
        For x = CInt(p1.X) To CInt(p2.X)
            Plot(x, y)
            err += Δerr
            While err >= 0.5
                Plot(x, y)
                y += yDirn
                err -= 1.0
            End While
        Next
    End Sub

    Function IsOnLine(p1 As Point, p2 As Point, testPoint As Point) As Boolean
        ' check for bounds
        If testPoint.X < p1.X - 0.5 OrElse testPoint.X > p2.X + 0.5 OrElse testPoint.Y < p1.Y - 0.5 OrElse testPoint.Y > p2.Y + 0.5 Then
            Return False
        End If

        Dim Δx = p2.X - p1.X
        Dim Δy = p2.Y - p1.Y
        Dim m = Δy / Δx
        Dim c = p1.Y - m * p1.X

        Return Math.Abs((m * Math.Round(testPoint.X, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) + c - Math.Round(testPoint.Y, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))) <= 0.5

    End Function

    Sub Main()
        ClearChart()

        ' end-points of the line
        Dim p1 = New Point(1, 1)
        Dim p2 = New Point(11, 5)

        DrawLine(p1, p2)

        ShowChart("Bresenham line:")

        ClearChart()

        For j = 0 To 9
            For i = 0 To 15
                Dim thisPoint = New Point(i, j)
                If IsOnLine(p1, p2, thisPoint) Then
                    Plot(thisPoint)
                End If
            Next
        Next

        ShowChart("Points on the line by brute-force:")

        ' a couple of points to go with the illustration on SO:
        Console.WriteLine(IsOnLine(p1, p2, New Point(7.51, 4.4)))
        Console.WriteLine(IsOnLine(p1, p2, New Point(7.51, 4.6)))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

I charted both the pixels as generated by the algorithm and then tested every pixel to see it would be on the line generated by the algorithm:

```
Bresenham line:
················
·██·············
···██···········
·····███········
········██······
··········██····
················
················
················
················

Points on the line by brute-force:
················
·██·············
···██···········
·····███········
········██······
··········██····
················
················
················
················
```

(It looked much better in a console window...ahem.)

Although it is hardly proof of correctness, you can see that it correctly determined if points would have been plotted for the data sample used.

Going back to the first picture, it correctly determines that (7.51, 4.4) is plotted and (7.51, 4.6) is not if you put those values into `IsOnLine()`.

Note that there are some points on the real line which are not included in the pixels generated by Bresenham's line algorithm, such as (4.51, 2.404) in this example. `IsOnLine()` returns `False` for those points.

Comment: How is IsOnLine supposed to work when it's a straight line? p2.X - p1.X would be 0, and so when you try to get m, there's an issue there. Do we just exit out with true earlier when that's the case?

Comment: @Robin That seems to be a good idea.

Comment: Cool, and sorry one more question, it looks like `IsOnLine` doesn't cover all cases right? From my implementation it looked like it doesnt cover the case where the slope is > 1. Would make sense considering all the implementations I saw of Bresenham's algo have different cases for when x grows faster than y and vice versa, but just wanted to see if you could confirm, i could have made a mistake.

Comment: @Robin Well spotted! Yes, you may need to make adjustments for the other seven octants.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this as an answer, even though it's only a very partial answer.

I believe the answer is yes. Writing a proof of it, however, is rather a bit of work and at minimum would require TeX support to be understandable. Instead, here are the key ideas to develop a proof.

Consider a slope m between 0 and 1. This is general enough, you can get the other three sections by reflections. Brensenham's algorithm gives you a sequence of horizontal runs, each rising by 1. The lengths of these runs are always either n or n+1, where n <= 1/m <= n+1. So you can think of a Brensenham line as binary sequence of 0 and 1. This much is elementary.

What's much less obvious is that this sequence is governed by the continued fraction expansion of m. Consider the error term m - 1/(n+1) from the above inequality. This yields the first "correction slope" by approximating the slope m from below with the slope 1/(n+1). Iterate this process to get a sequence of correction slopes that converge to m. It will become clear that these correction slope are simply a transform of the continued fraction sequence. You can also see that the 0/1 sequence above is a set of ever-larger quasisubperiods whose hierarchy is another transform of the continued fraction expansion.

To check your understanding of this, one consequence is these relationships is that if m is rational, so its continued fraction expansion is finite, that the Brensenham sequence is periodic.

This gives you something more powerful than a predicate test. You can use the sequence of correction slopes to calculate the y-coordinate for an arbitrary x-coordinate. Simply multiple all the correction slopes by x. Add up enough of them until the error bound interval (you get alternating upper and lower bounds) is entirely with an integral range, that is, n <= a < b < n+1.

Answer (score 1):

For a first octant line segment (`Dx > Dy > 0`), the pixels are

```
X = X0 + I
Y = Y0 + (I.Dy + R) / Dx
```

where `R` is a rounding constant (usually `Dx / 2`).

Then it suffices to check

```
Y == Y0 + ((X - X0).Dy + R) / Dx
```

---

You can rewrite the criterion like

```
0 <= (X - X0).Dy + R - (Y - Y0).Dx < Dx
```

You need to adapt the relations for the other octants.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Andrew Morton's code in python.
Only works for the first quadrant x > y or 100 > 25 .  I plot only if x, y evaluates to a bresenham line.  I know you said no plotting, but plotting is only used for demonstration. There are still 8 otherquadrants

```
def andrew_morton_bresenham(x0,y0,x1,y1,filename):
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
    im = Image.new('1', (100,100))
    plot_func = lambda x,y,val: im.putpixel((x,y),val)

    for x in range(im.width):
        for y in range(im.height): 
            delta_x = x1-x0 #Dim Δx = p2.X - p1.X
            delta_y = y1-y0 #Dim Δy = p2.Y - p1.Y
            slope=delta_y / delta_x #m = Δy / Δx
            c = y0 - slope * x0 #Dim c = p1.Y - m * p1.X
            eval_line = abs(slope * x + c - y)
            if (eval_line <= 0.5):
                plot_func(x,y,1)
    im.save(filename)

andrew_morton_bresenham(0,0, 100,25,'bresenham-functional-copy-stackflow.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are looking for a first method to find if point exists on bresenham line. I am looking for a better solution but here is what I do as of now;

1. Actually generate the line pixels and store them in a list or vector. Its best if you made your own point() or pixel() class or struct.
   That class should have comparison capabilities written by you.
   The line pixels or points should be sorted within that list.
2. Simply perform a custom(personally written) binary search on the line to find the pixel.

Using this method, if the line is already sorted and exists, he search should be O(log2N)

Comment: I said specifically "without actually generating the line". Your answer requires the line to be generated first.